# Is it possible to grow yeast from fruits?

Tags: yeast

In my country the yeast for brewing is not available, so people use baking yeast instead of it.
It works but obviously it's not ideal.
I've seen a video that the person was making natural yeast from raisins and grape but when I try to do the same procedure it doesn't work well.

I was wondering if there is a way to grow yeast from fruits? or anything that is available in all the countries :))

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer, yes it is possible. Will you get a desirable wine yeast, from grapes maybe, from plums, less likely. Will they ferment a mixture of sugars yes, will it taste good... maybe.

There are thousands of species and strains of yeast if not millions, or more. Yes you can plate up isolate and then culture up yeast/bacteria/etc... but you do need to know what you are doing. and if plating up to isolate before culturing then you need to be aware of the risks(see identifying video).

Hopefully these videos help explain it a bit better than I can without writing you an essay on microbiology.

Capturing wild yeast 1.2.3

- Capture the yeast - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqcc9ZeLBXM
- Purify the yeast - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDvGvBVw3gg
- Identifying organisms - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abQNl6WIdc8

Isolating yeasts from plums - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=85IXCUdhobQ

Streak plating - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mCOtWztCObY

Home yeast lab made easy serise - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WtXrsvNLCxk&list=PLZ3Z2428mCTqDFK-3ZSNpZBXJfTaMtRXE

Comment: Additionally, you could also start from sourdough starters and see what they deliver. Experiment with different flours, feed them for at least fourteen days. Then use them to ferment wort or sugar solutions (but sugar solutions then would probably need yeast nutrients).

Comment: with sour dough starters you often end up with a blend of lacto and Brett, you could get a lovely tangy brew